# Как поставить эти два элемента друг под другом?

Tags: bootstrap

Как поставить эти два элемента другпод другом

```html
                <div class="call-phone"><img src="/image/phone-icon.png" alt="">
                    
                    <strong>8 (800) 350-07-19</strong>sapi.restorator@gmail.com 
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить перенос `<br>`, а можно применить `display:block`, например, с помощью параграфов:

```html
<div class="call-phone">
  <img src="/image/phone-icon.png" alt="">
  <p><strong>8 (800) 350-07-19</strong></p>
  <p>sapi.restorator@gmail.com</p>
</div>
```

Если нужно, чтобы картинка была слева от обеих подписей, нужна дополнительная вёрстка:

```css
.call-phone img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1em;
}

.call-phone-text {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="call-phone">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/35/35" alt="">
  <div class="call-phone-text">
    <p><strong>8 (800) 350-07-19</strong></p>
    <p>sapi.restorator@gmail.com</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Прочитай про [Media object](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/media-object/) в Bootstrap

Вот пример оттуда:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="media">
      <img class="mr-3" src="..." alt="Generic placeholder image">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mt-0">Media heading</h5>
        Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
      </div>
</div>
```